# Selenium unable to connect to ChromeDriver 75 on Mac

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We are upgrading a *previously-working* Selenium/Java/Chrome test configuration, to newer versions:

```
ChromeDriver           2.35 -> 75.0.3770.90
Selenium Java          3.14 -> 3.141.59

macOS                  10.14.5       (unchanged)
Java                   11.0.3        (unchanged)
Chrome                 75.0.3770.100 (unchanged)
```

However, when attempting to run a Selenium test, we see:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28719
```

The full stack/log:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}) on port 28719
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Jun 26, 2019 10:45:03 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C


...


org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28719
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Craigs-iMac.local', ip: '192.168.1.131', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '11.0.3'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByTagName(RemoteWebDriver.java:396)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElement(By.java:320)
```

All the resources I've found in this area suggest using `--whitelisted-ips=''`, which did not have an effect, or were related to **incompatible** Selenium/Chrome/ChromeDriver versions, which I don't think is the issue here.

**Update:** I can confirm that the driver starts, and is listening on port `28719`, but then **stops** at some point between startup and execution of the actual test. I've found no errors/logging related to the shutdown.

**Update 2:** I've debugged, and the initial commands sent to the remote driver succeed (`setWindowSize()`), **but this line causes the driver to die silently**:

```
((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage().setItem("token", token);
```

Comment: can you share the code which is causing the failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems newer versions of the ChromeDriver (*Or Selenium? I don't know.*) launch Chrome with an initial page sitting at the URL `data:`.

By adding these system properties prior to instantiating the `ChromeDriver`:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "/Users/craig/chromedriver.log");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
```

I was able to glean the following right before the driver quits:

```
[1561563455.971][INFO]: [01517094c63c0dd609c06a5622afe6b1] RESPONSE ExecuteScript ERROR <unknown>: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.
  (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.100)
```

So by changing this call in my test utility code:

```
((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage().setItem("token", token);
```

To this:

```
if (driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("data:")) {
    // Driver will quit if we try to access localStorage without a page load
    driver.get("/");
}
((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage().setItem("token", token);
```

Everything is now fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HiJE.gif

Answer (score -1):

Editing:

LocalStorage is available only after launching any website. ie after driver.get

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/html5/LocalStorage.html

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not resolved after a clean/restart.

Comment: YEs, it is with LocalStorage, able to reproduce the error

Comment: ok, it is simple. It is available only after using driver.get . Please launch the site and then use it. Update the Reply.